# Using Pixi with Simpleheat and Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, heatmap, pixi.js

I'm trying to apply some post-processing effects to a HTML5 canvas-based experience I'm creating. I'm using a library called simpleheat to apply heat effects to the map. This works with a regular canvas, but the effect doesn't appear when I'm using a PIXI-based one. The code is below. Does anyone know what the issue might be here?

Simpleheat Library: https://github.com/mourner/simpleheat/blob/gh-pages/README.md

```
// Width and height of map
let width = 1145;
let height = 641;

// Bind canvas to existing map container
let canvasLayer = d3
  .select("#map")
  .append("canvas")
  .attr("id", "map-canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// TODO: Add D3 instance to the generated Pixi Canvas + filters
let app = new PIXI.Application({
  width: width,
  height: height,
  transparent: true,
});

// Add Pixi instance to the document
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const canvas = app.renderer.plugins.extract.canvas(app.stage);
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
graphics.endFill();
app.stage.addChild(graphics);


function generateMapAndContrails() {
  // Load GeoJSON data and merge with states data
  d3.json(
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9f6a63841a74562a4a7173b9f7033e83/raw/aafb03b49f258cbfeec816a7bf5c92288a06193c/us-states.json",
    function (json) {
      d3.json(`data/${sliderVal}.json`, function (data) {

        // Draw our heatmap onto Pixi to be able to apply effects
        let heat = simpleheat(canvas);
        console.log(heat);

        // set data of [[x, y, value], ...] format
        heat.data([
          [150, 150, 1],
          [750.508, 300.906, 1],
          [720.508, 270.906, 0.7],
          [760.508, 250.906, 0.5],
          [780.508, 270.906, 0.8],
          [680.508, 270.906, 0.8],
          [300.508, 270.906, 0.8],
          [300.508, 310.906, 0.7],
          [550.508, 490.906, 0.8],
          [510.508, 490.906, 0.5],
          [900.508, 590.906, 0.7],
        ]);

        // set point radius and blur radius (25 and 15 by default)
        heat.radius(25, 15);

        // optionally customize gradient colors, e.g. below
        // (would be nicer if d3 color scale worked here)
        heat.gradient({
          0: "#430758",
          0.2: "#3F2E72",
          0.3: "#3B4F89",
          0.4: "#2E708B",
          0.5: "#279787",
          0.6: "#3CAA79",
          0.7: "#6ACB5D",
          0.8: "#C4DC3A",
          1: "#FCE625",
        });

        // set maximum for domain
        heat.max(1);

        // draw into canvas, with minimum opacity threshold
        heat.draw(0.05);

      });
    }
  );

generateMapAndContrails();
```